# make gnus/emacs to place inbound emails per folders

Tags: linux, email, emacs

I have a gmail account, and have set up gnus to read my email over IMAP. I'm also subscribed to a few mailing lists, and want them to be placed in individual directories, e.g. ml-openstack, ml-dpdk etc. so that when I open gnus, I have them not in INBOX, but in ml-openstack, ml-dpdk and so forth.

What should I tweak in emacs/gnus configuration to achieve this? Thanks.

Comment: Have you considered configuring rules in Gmail to achieve this?